# Google maps custom layer with clickable markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is there a way to ad a custom layer on top of Google maps without loosing the option to click on marker?

https://jsfiddle.net/hxyn9Lae/3/

So far I have this code, but the markers are not click-able anymore. And I don't want to use InfoWindow, because the layer will be much complicated in the future.

```
var locations = [];


// Locations
locations = [
  ['1', 'Colliers Wood Station', 51.418187, -0.178096],
  ['2', 'Tandem Centre', 51.413675, -0.1772],
  ['3', 'Horatio Nelson Memorial', 51.413728, -0.192231]
];

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var layer = `
            <div class="map-layer">
                <h6></h6>
            </div>
        `;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                title: locations[i][1],
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
                map: map
            });

            bounds.extend(marker.position);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    $('#map-canvas').prepend(layer);
                    $('#map-canvas h6').text(locations[i][1]);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
}


initialize();
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code is using an overlaid div and not a true [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays), you can still achieve the desired behavior by disabling `pointer-events` in the CSS for the overlaid `div` (in your case, it's the CSS for the `map-layer` class).

This allows you to "click through" the `div` that's layered over the map.

Example using your fiddle code:

```js
var locations = [];

// Locations
locations = [
  ['1', 'Colliers Wood Station', 51.418187, -0.178096],
  ['2', 'Tandem Centre', 51.413675, -0.1772],
  ['3', 'Horatio Nelson Memorial', 51.413728, -0.192231]
];

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: true,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


  var layer = `
            <div class="map-layer">
             <h6></h6>
            </div>
        `;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      title: locations[i][1],
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
      map: map
    });

    bounds.extend(marker.position);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        $('#map-canvas').prepend(layer);
        $('#map-canvas h6').text(locations[i][1]);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
    map.setZoom(14);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
  });

}


initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.map-layer {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Note that you can also enable `pointer-events` on child elements, even if they're disabled on parent elements.

Comment: This sound good, thank's for the advice. I noticed I actually didn't explained well what I need. I don't actually need to click on the marker, I would like to change the clicked icon's path, e.g. https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png and move above the layer, so it would be emphasised. Updated https://jsfiddle.net/hxyn9Lae/5/

Comment: Updated JS Fiddle with the close function https://jsfiddle.net/hxyn9Lae/7/
So the only thing is missing to move the clicked marker above the layer somehow.

Comment: I created a new version using polygon, but now all the markers above the layer. I need to move all the markers under the layer except the I just clicked. https://jsfiddle.net/hxyn9Lae/9/

Comment: @levipadre You could set the opacity of the other markers to make them appear as if they're behind the clicked marker. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmg157/ntfejsxk/ You would need to add a line to reset the opacity for the other non-clicked markers after a second, third, etc. marker is clicked, but that should be pretty straight-forward using the same code.

Comment: I saw this answer was recently downvoted. Any explanation so I can improve the answer?